# where condition for first row of every id pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df as:

```
id     items    price    less
 a    Fruits     120      20
 a    Fruits     220      20
 a    Fruits     320      20
 b    Fruits     120      50
 b    Fruits     280      20
 b    Fruits     320      20
```

I want to manipulate the value of price column for only first row of every id by subtracting the less column value like

```
id    items    price 
 a   Fruits     100    #120-20(less value)
 a   Fruits     220 
 a   Fruits     320 
 b   Fruits     70     #120-50
 b   Fruits     280 
 b   Fruits     320
```

It should be for only first row of every id.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `duplicated` over `id` column (which, by default, marks first ones as not duplicates) and `np.where` to choose what to do:

```
df["new_price"] = np.where(df.duplicated("id"), df.price, df.price - df.less)
```

to get

```
>>> df

  id   items  price  less  new_price
0  a  Fruits    120    20        100
1  a  Fruits    220    20        220
2  a  Fruits    320    20        320
3  b  Fruits    120    50         70
4  b  Fruits    280    20        280
5  b  Fruits    320    20        320
```

Comment: `df.duplicated` return first duplicate element `False` and the others `True`. I think you should write `~df.duplicated` to get the correct result.

Comment: @AliIrani That's handled by the position of the values after the condition in `np.where`. Since it marks firsts `False`, `df.price - df.less` is assigned to those places.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mustafa Aydın it is giving an error :   raise keyerror(diff)

Comment: @naina Can you please share the full error along with the traceback?

Comment: I am unable to..Can you please tell me any other method of doing this

Comment: @naina I don't understand, sorry. Does the above code work? If not, what is the error?

Comment: ValueError: operand could not be broadcast together with shapes (566,) (566,)

Comment: @naina Where is the rest of the error, please?

Comment: @naina Are you sure that's the error? Because those shapes are indeed broadcastable (they are the same...)
For `np.where` to give such an error, there ought to be a 3rd array's shape in the error... Can you paste the error message from where it says `Traceback..`?